# How to view "generated HTML code" in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, code-generation, firebug, firefox-addon, web-developer-toolbar

If using Firebug, we can click on the HTML tab, and click to expand each element to see the generated HTML code.  Is there a way to expand it all or get a plain text file?

I just accidentally found out that there doesn't even need to be Firebug.  We can just press CTRL-A (to select all) on the webpage, and then right click and choose "View Selection Source", then we will get a plain text file of the "current HTML code", even will see a `<div>` that is the Firebug panel that is before the `<body>` tag if Firebug is open.  But it seems like a weird way to invoke this.  Is there any other way?

(**Update**: generated HTML usually refers to the HTML after JavaScript changes the DOM.  It is the current DOM tree instead of the original source code)

Comment: +1 for Selecting area and right click and choose "View Selection Source", which does not require any additional plugins.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Firebug's HTML tab, right-click the root node and select "copy HTML". Then paste to a text editor.

Without Firefox Add-Ons, you could use a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) like this:

```
javascript: var win = window.open(); win.document.write('<html><head><title>Generated HTML of  ' + location.href + '</title></head><pre>' + document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;') + '</pre></html>'); win.document.close(); void 0;
```

Comment: Got pop-up blocker errors. Disabled the pop-up blocker, still got errors. May have something to do with pdf.js. Workaround: `document.body.onclick = function() { /* the code */ };` and then click anywhere in the document. There I fixed it!

Comment: nice hack, but one must keep in mind that whitespaces get lost.

Comment: Works, however no javascript generated source inside, this is the same as CTRL+A

Answer (score 18):

With the [Web Developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) add-on, select **View Source** - **View Generated Source**. And if you want to view the original source, select **View Source** - **View Source** (or simply press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>)

Comment: Superb tool. It's so extensive compared to the FF devtool

Comment: That toolbar was my lifeline, but now this key feature isn't there :(

Comment: As of Firefox 68.0.2(32bit) with web developer toolbar 2.0.1, View Source is no longer in the menu.

Answer (score 5):

Using the Firefox DevTools (integrated in FF since version 35) you can view the generated HTML opening the web inspector (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>) and selecting the *HTML* tab.

You can copy the generated HTML by right clicking on `<html>` and selecting *Copy inner HTML*.

Comment: This doesn't appear to show generated source (i.e. it doesn't reflect changes made by JavaScript). Perhaps changed in Firefox 57?

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a programmatic solution, you can just feed the document into an XMLSerializer.

Comment: how exactly should this work ? how can the XMLSerializer know what is exactly rendered?

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if I understood your question well, but here is something really simple and you won't need another addon.

Every browser has a native function to view the source-code of the actual page, just right-click and look for something that resembles "source" or "code".

In Firefox for example it's just "Souce-code", in Chrome it is "View Page Source" and so on.

That being said, Web Developer toolbar is indeed a great addon, especially if you do CSS too.

Comment: the "generated HTML code" usually refer to the HTML generated by Javascript modifying the DOM.  the resultant HTML.