# jQuery - Way to view jQuery generated html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to view the jQuery (or Javascript) generated HTML - for example, see the jQuery-modified source of a page that uses a number of `prepend()`'s `html()`'s etc.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to view "generated HTML code" in Firefox? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314429/how-to-view-generated-html-code-in-firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inspect the page with firefox addon [FireBug](https://web.archive.org/web/20101226133037/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/) though:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gnucitizen.org](http://www.gnucitizen.org/static/blog/2007/04/firebug-splash.jpg))</sub>

Comment: What about `$('html').html()`?

Answer (score 4):

Use Firebug to look at the current DOM, although it is an interpretation of the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) as the other answers suggest, you can also use the built-in [Chrome developer tools](http://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/devtools/google-chrome-developer-tools-tutorial):
[image]

To access the tools you can do it the same way as Firebug, just right click and select **Inspect Element**.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Web Developer plug-in for FireFox.  Then Right click on the page, the select Web Developer -> View Source -> View generated source